# Is there a name for the standard deviation of the products of z-scores attached to two variables?

Tags: correlation

Apologies if this has been answered somewhere else on this site, but here goes...

Consider two finite sets of quantitative data $X=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ and $Y=\{y_1,\dots,y_n\}$ having means $\bar X$ and $\bar Y$, and standard deviations $s_X$ and $s_Y$, respectively. The correlation coefficient $r$ associated to $X$ and $Y$ is more-or-less the mean of the data $Z=\{z(x_1)z(y_1),\dots, z(x_n)z(y_n)\}$,
$$
r=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{z(x_i)z(y_i)}{n-1},
$$
where $z(x_i)=\frac{x_i-\bar X}{s_X}$ denotes the usual $z$-score for the data point $x_i$. The $r$-value is (obviously) a very useful invariant, as it summarize both the direction and strength of linearly associated variables. Does the standard deviation $s_Z$ of $Z$ also have a common name and is it also a "useful" summary statistic? (You can interpret "useful" however you like here. Specifically, have you personally ever used this statistic? In what context?)

Comment: 1. Your use of $z$ and $Z$ in very different ways flouts the usual conventions and may lead to some confusion (I missed the odd way you defined $Z$ initially, so it definitely confused me). 2. The small-sample standard error of $r$ changes depending on the value of $\rho$ and the sample size even under an assumption of bivariate normality.